# EOL error (unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)')

Tags: bash, shell

If I start the script from this error:

```
./Sinusbot.sh: line 276: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./Sinusbot.sh: line 305: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Part of the affected script:

```
echo -e "$info Configuring instances"
if [ "$ydl" = "y" ] || [ "$ydl" = "Y" ]; then
    c2="0"
    while [ $c2 = $nbot ]
    do
        c2=$((c2+1)                     #Line 276
        bport=$((bport+1)
        cd
        cd Sinus-$2
        cat > config.ini << EOL
        ListenPort = ${bport}
        ListenHost = "0.0.0.0"
        TS3Path = "TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_linux_amd64"
        YoutubeDLPath = "youtube-dl"
        DataDir = "data/"
        EOL
    done
else
    while [ $c2 = $nbot ]
    do
        c2=$((c2+1)
        bport=$((bport+1)
        cd
        cd Sinus-$2
        cat > config.ini << EOL
        ListenPort = ${bport}
        ListenHost = "0.0.0.0"
        TS3Path = "TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_linux_amd64"
        DataDir = "data/"
        EOL
    done
fi
                                   #line 305
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

In addition to notepad ++ all the lines appear blue since I put "cat" config.ini << EOL "how come? And how can I take it off?

[image notepad ++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGNwM.png)

Comment: Arithmetic Expansion - $(())

Comment: A.... Ok, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetic Expansion - `$(())`
close missed parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

These lines have 2 starting parenthesis but only one finishing parenthesis:

```
    c2=$((c2+1)
    bport=$((bport+1)
```

Considering the indentation of your program, you probably want to close them by adding a closing parenthesis top each line:

```
    c2=$((c2+1))
    bport=$((bport+1))
```